# Umbraco Custom 404 Error Page Not Working

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404, umbraco

I am using using Umbraco 4.7 and my server is IIS7 was wondering what is not going right for me. I basically want to make a custom error page (404) and everything I have tried is not working, checked the forums, but it is still showing the same problem.

I have edited my umbracoSettings.config

```xml
<errors>
   <!-- the id of the page that should be shown if the page is not found -->
   <!-- <errorPage culture="default">1647</errorPage> -->
   <!-- <errorPage culture="en-US">1647</errorPage> -->
   <error404>1647</error404>
</errors>
```

Also I have looked about saying adding this to the web.config file.

```xml
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
   <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Any help would highly appreciated. I am a complete novice to IIS and anything involving network settings.

Comment: Manage to resolve this, Going to IIS > Sites > Mywebsite > Error Pages  > 404 > Edit feature settings > change local requests to detailed erros. and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure that 1647 is node id of the 404 page.

Also add the below code in the `system.webServer` tag in your web.config.

```xml
<httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="400" path="/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Hope this works...

Comment: I tried this but am getting the page to display the following text.

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone stumbles across this like I did when researching a similar problem with Umbraco 7, setting trySkipIisCustomErrors value to true in config/umbracoSettings.config file did it for me.

```xml
  <web.routing
    trySkipIisCustomErrors="true"
    internalRedirectPreservesTemplate="false">
  </web.routing>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the exact solution to my problem!

Comment: This was the solution for me! Annoyingly everything was meant to be identical between dev and staging. trySkipIisCustomErrors was set to false on dev, but had to be set to true on staging! Silly machines!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem, and the solution suggested by Sobin P Samuel worked for me (just copy and paste the httpErrors element directly to the system.webserver section in your Web.Config-file), so I guess this is also what resolved it for paulstewart185...

Please note that according to http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/configuring-404-pages the solution for IIS 7.5 would be to add the following to the system.webserver section:

```xml
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
```